# How to select more than one record using MySQL Group by?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, opencart

I can't seem to use `distinct` or `group by` to group certain mySQL records together. This SQL query below just returns one line each - I want all the values in the CID though..

I want to select a random group by cid or the first set in the table.. I cant use AND CID=X .. is there a way to do it without ..

Table

```
id      pid     image                           sort_order      cid
-----
2474    50      data/low.jpg            2                       56
2473    50      data/hi.jpg             3                       59
2471    50      data/thumn.jpg      500                     59
2472    50      data/front.jpg      1000                    56
2470    50      data/back.jpg           1                       56
```

Query

```
SELECT *
FROM `ocm1__product_image`
WHERE `product_id` = '50'
GROUP BY `cid`
ORDER BY `ocm1__product_image`.`sort_order` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This should return

```
id      pid     image                           sort_order      cid
2474    50      data/low.jpg            2                       56
2472    50      data/front.jpg      1000                    56
2470    50      data/back.jpg           1                       56
```

But it returns both colours.. can I not unique the group?

It returns this which is wrong, I want to list all cid unique values

```
id      pid     image                           sort_order      cid
2474    50      data/low.jpg            2                       56
2471    50      data/thumn.jpg      500                     59
```

Comment: Er, just replacing the `group by` by `and cid=56` will give the result you're describing...? I can't quite grasp the question :)

Comment: I can't carry that value across @JoachimIsaksson I know about this already I just want to select a group without the Id

Comment: ``SELECT *
FROM `Table1`
WHERE `pid` = '50'
and  `cid` = '56'
ORDER BY `sort_order` ASC`` : should give you the o/p you are looking for !

Comment: @NoobUnChained read my comment above. There must be a way to use a GROUP and DISTINCT or UNIQUE without using AND X = Y

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid So you just want just _any one random group_?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: Just check my answer if it serves your purpose.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I want to select either a random group by the cid or the first set of cid in the table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return all the entries with the lowest `cid` for the requested `pid`.
It gives the same result as you say that you need, without giving a specific `cid` as a condition;

```
SELECT o1.*
FROM `ocm1__product_image` o1
LEFT JOIN `ocm1__product_image` o2
  ON o1.pid=o2.pid AND o1.cid > o2.cid
WHERE o1.`pid` = '50' AND o2.cid IS NULL
ORDER BY `o1`.`sort_order` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b252/4).

Comment: Does this select the first set or a random set?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid It selects the set with the lowest `cid`, which, if they're numbered sequentially, would mean the first.

Comment: Repped and Marked. This is quite a neat solution and really fast too.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `group by` to sort them, you just need to use `order by` in addition you must also sort them using the `CID` value for specific `Customer ID` only, You have the value `Product ID (PID)` but you didn't provide the CID value into your samples.

```
SELECT *
FROM `ocm1__product_image`
WHERE `product_id` = '50' and `cid` = '56'
ORDER BY `ocm1__product_image`.`sort_order` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

---

or if you want to sort them using the `ID`, to know where is the first data inserted by using the `primary key`

```
SELECT *
FROM `ocm1__product_image`
WHERE `product_id` = '50' and `cid` = '56'
ORDER BY `ocm1__product_image`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```